# How to test a controller mocking a service with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a angular controller mocking the calls made to a factory using jasmine. My controller is like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  function initScoresController(scoresFactory){
    var vm = this;
    vm.projects = {};
    vm.month = {};
    vm.month.users = {};
    vm.tally = {};
    vm.tally.projects = {};

    scoresFactory.projectsCurrentMonthScores().success(
      function(data){
        vm.projects = data;
      }
    );

    scoresFactory.usersCurrentMonthScores().success(
      function(data){
        vm.month.users = data;
      }
    );

    scoresFactory.projectCurrentMonthTally().success(
      function(data){
        vm.tally.projects = data;
      }
    );
  }

  angular.module('project.dashboard')
    .controller('ScoresController',  ['scoresFactory', initScoresController])
})();
```

My factory like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  function setupScoresFactory($http, PROJECTS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES, USERS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES, PROJECT_CURRENT_MONTH_TALLY){

    var scoresFactory = {};

    scoresFactory.projectsCurrentMonthScores = function(){
      return $http.get(PROJECTS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES);
    };

    scoresFactory.usersCurrentMonthScores = function(){
      return $http.get(USERS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES);
    };

    scoresFactory.projectCurrentMonthTally = function(){
      return $http.get(PROJECT_CURRENT_MONTH_TALLY);
    };

    return scoresFactory;

  };

  angular
    .module('project.dashboard', ["config"])
    .factory('scoresFactory', ['$http', 'PROJECTS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES', 'USERS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES', 'PROJECT_CURRENT_MONTH_TALLY', setupScoresFactory]);
})();
```

And my test:

```
describe('dashboard scores controller', function(){
 describe('projectCurrentMonthTally function', function(){
   var controller, scoresCtrl, scoresFactoryMock;

   beforeEach(module('config'));
   beforeEach(module('project.dashboard'));

   beforeEach(
     inject(function(_$controller_, _scoresFactory_){
       controller = _$controller_;
       scoresFactoryMock = _scoresFactory_;

       jasmine.spyOn(scoresFactoryMock, 'projectsCurrentMonthScores').andReturn(function(){console.log('fake project current month')});

       scoresCtrl = controller('ScoresController', {scoresFactory: scoresFactoryMock});
     }));

    it('it should return a collection of votes for every project', function(){
      expect(scoresFactoryMock.projectsCurrentMonthScores).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
 });
});
```

My test throws this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8081/base/test/spec/dashboard/dashboard.scores.controller.js:13:16)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8081/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473:17)
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost:8081/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2401:20)
```

I believe that the problem is on my success() calls. How can I test this controller, mocking the calls made to my factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your factory method is supposed to return a promise but you are returning a function in your mock. At least you need to return something that has a `success()` method.

An easy fix that makes the error go away would be:

```
jasmine.spyOn(scoresFactoryMock,'projectsCurrentMonthScores').andReturn({
    success: function() { console.log('fake project current month') }
});
```

**BUT:**

I recommend not to return the extended promise obtained from `$http` in your factory since it contains the special `success()` method which not all promises have (promises usually only have a `then()` method). I recommend you change your factory like that:

```
scoresFactory.projectsCurrentMonthScores = function(){
    return $http.get(PROJECTS_CURRENT_MONTH_SCORES).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Of course you have to change your controller like that:

```
scoresFactory.projectsCurrentMonthScores().then(function(data){
    vm.projects = data;
});
```

But this way your controller doesn't care whether the data was obtained from an $http call or some other way (actually your controller shouldn't care!).

In your mock you can create a promise using the $q service like this:

```
jasmine.spyOn(scoresFactoryMock, 'projectsCurrentMonthScores').andCallFake(function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Comment: I made the corrections you suggested, but still had the same error.

Comment: Two things: 1) In your code it says jasmine.spyOn(...). I think it should be only spyOn(...). At least it doesn't work with jasmine 1.3. 2) I recommend you change all methods in your factory according to my suggestions and you spy on them all because they will be called in the test.

Comment: I made a fiddle of your code and you can see it works (I commented out the other methods that are not spied upon). http://jsfiddle.net/L8kbzced/2/ The current code shows the problem you are observing. Around line 85 you can see the changes I suggested in a comment. Just uncomment it and delete the old part and you see it works.